# How to enforce valid json in elastic search?

Tags: java, json, validation, elasticsearch

Consider following code:

```
function add_document() {
    index=$1
    _type=$2
    json="$3"

    curl -s -X PUT "$NODE_ADDRESS/index/_type?pretty" -d "$json"
}

add_document users documents '{user_name : "kshitiz"}'
```

The above function runs just fine and adds the document to the index. The problem however is that `{user_name : "kshitiz"}` isn't valid JSON.

I can validate the JSON in my code before sending to Elastic but the problem is that this instance would be shared among a large team. A better solution would be to disable invalid JSON as acceptable documents at the node so that add operation would fail and force developers to code properly.

How can I enable strict JSON validation in Elastic?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this functionality in plugin. Have a look at examples:

[Validate data before indexing them](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/SMkXDEMFJL4/dL5SK13MWogJ)
[Implementing data validation in ElasticSearch](https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/implementing-data-validation-in-elasticsearch/)

Answer (score 0):

Use mappings which are basically schema for docs in ES doc types. This mapping will do only type checks for keys and associated value.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_explicit_mappings